# Whats wrong with my query, should i use WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, what am i doing wrong?

This query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (art_nr, article, balance, list_type) 
     VALUES('$art_nr', '$article', '$balance', '$list_type')
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE balance = sum(balance + '$quantity_ordered');
     UPDATE table2 SET list = 'History' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Will give me this error:

> Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use
> of group function

This query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (art_nr, article, balance, list_type) VALUES('$art_nr', '$article', '$balance', '$list_type')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE balance = sum(balance + '$quantity_ordered') WHERE art_nr = '$art_nr';
        UPDATE table2 SET list = 'History' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Will give me this error:

> Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near 'WHERE art_nr = 'S2Bygel'; UPDATE purchase_orderlist SET
> list' at line 2

**UPDATE**

This was my first query. With Params:

```
    //SECURITY
    $params_array= array(
        ':id' => $_POST['formData']['id'],
        ':art_nr' => $_POST['formData']['art_nr'],
        ':article' => $_POST['formData']['article'],
        ':quantity_ordered' => $_POST['formData']['quantity_ordered'],
        ':list_type' => $_POST['formData']['list_type']
    );
     
    //QUERY
    $query = "INSERT INTO table1 (art_nr, article, balance, list_type) VALUES (:art_nr, :article, :balance, :list_type)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE balance = balance + VALUES(:quantity_ordered) WHERE art_nr = :art_nr;
                UPDATE table2 SET list = 'History' WHERE id = :id";
```

The problem with this query is that im running two querys at the same time. and then i will get this error:

```
Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

**SUCCESS**

I had to use prepared statements and separate my two querys:

```
        //SECURITY
    $params_array= array(
        ':art_nr' => $_POST['formData']['art_nr'],
        ':article' => $_POST['formData']['article'],
        ':quantity_ordered' => $_POST['formData']['quantity_ordered'],
        ':list_type' => $_POST['formData']['list_type']
    );
     
    //QUERY
    $query = "INSERT INTO table1
                (art_nr, article, balance, list_type)
                VALUES (:art_nr, :article, :quantity_ordered, :list_type)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                art_nr = art_nr, article = article, balance = balance + :quantity_ordered, list_type = list_type";
                
    //EXECUTE
    try{ 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($params_array);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }
    
    //SECURITY
    $params_array= array(
        ':id' => $_POST['formData']['id']
    );
     
    //QUERY
    $query = "UPDATE table2 SET list = 'History' WHERE id = :id";
                
    //EXECUTE
    try{ 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($params_array);
        echo "success";
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }
```

Comment: You can run a single SQL statement at a time. Either an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`, both not both. Run them separately.

Comment: Where do the variables come from? PHP code? Please be warned that your queries might be open for SQL injection

Comment: PDO will not allow the execution of 2 queries in the same `execute. I notice you dont actually show how you are submitting these queries. Why is that?

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok. So i must separate them. I didn't think that the submitting was the problem.

Comment: Well a string of characters in a text literal is almost never a problem

Comment: You probably also need to consider doing the 2 queries inside a transaction, as the changes would appear to be closely related and you woudl not want on one to be run on its own

Comment: We dont post SUCCESS or SOLVED comments into question. But you can answer your own question if you feel nobody elses answer is good enough. you can even accept your own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to add the value of `$quantity_ordered` to `balance` for the row? Then you don't need the `sum()` **aggregation** function. Just the `+` operator is enough.

But it seems like you're doing this in a host language like PHP. You should urgently learn to use parameterized queries! Do not use string concatenation (or interpolation) to get values in a query. That's error prone and may allow SQL injection attacks against your application.

Comment: On duplicate key i just want to update the balance column yes. I did remove the sum() but with no success. still same error. I normaly use parameterized querys with PDO but i culdnt do it in this query because i did not use all parameters in all querys. Maby i have to seperate the calls and use parameters again.

Comment: //QUERY
        $query = "INSERT INTO table1
                    (art_nr, article, balance, list_type)
                    VALUES (:art_nr, :article, :quantity_ordered, :list_type)
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    art_nr = art_nr, article = article, balance = balance + :quantity_ordered, list_type = list_type";

Comment: I have to do the other query in a new query.